# Translate latitude and longitude in X, Y coordinates

Tags: geolocation, utm

I have to translate latitude and longitude coordinates on X, Y plan. I have decided to use UTM as projection system. I use this page ( http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM ) to test and quickly get result. 
As test I wann plot on plan London and Rome. Rome has Latitude: 41.90 and Longitude: 12.48. London has Latitude: 51.50 and Longitude -0.12 expressed in degrees.

Using WGS84 and page reported first i've calculated Rome as Easting: 290965 and Northing: 4641744
London has Easting: 699889 and Northing: 5709362.

If I intend northing as the Y coordinate and easting as X coordinata Rome will be western than London and this is a huge mistake (don't you think?)

Where I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

UTM is based on more than just easting and northing, there is also the base reference grid from which the E and N are measured.  London and Rome are in different grids.

Comment: and so? How I have to complete calculus to get a proper x, y rapresentation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert here.  I only know that easting is based off the center line of the grid, and therefore two points with the same easting (but different grids) are not the same longitude.  There is an SE for GIS, maybe move this question over there?